# Imputing NA values in Destination location column with country capital based on destination_country column

Tags: python, dataframe, country

I have 2 columns in `shipcat_df` - `Destination Location` and `Destination_Country`
There are many NA values in the `Destination Location` column and I am trying to replace them with their capital based on `Destination_Country` column. Below is the code I tried to use:

```
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
shipcat_df['Destination Location'] = shipcat_df['Destination Location'].replace({'NA': [CountryInfo(shipcat_df['Destination_Country'])].capital()}, inplace=True)
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26188/610543798.py in <module>
  1 ##Creating a country capital column
  2 from countryinfo import CountryInfo
 ----> 3 shipcat_df['Destination_Location'] = shipcat_df['Destination 
  Location'].replace({'NA': [CountryInfo(shipcat_df['Destination_Country'])].capital()}, inplace=True)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\countryinfo\countryinfo.py in __init__(self, country_name)
 20             pass country name
 21         """
 ---> 22         self.__country_name = country_name.lower() if country_name else ''
 23         # get the files path
 24         __file_dir_path = dirname(realpath(__file__))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
1535     @final
1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
 1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: what kind of df module do you use (pandas, pySpark)? You could use a `case` statement and test `isnull()` with a syntax depending on your environment

Comment: @Christophe I am using pandas module. Can you please share an example? Thank you –

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas module, but the idea is to update the column and if it's null, put your default value. This can be achieved using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) clause and test the value thanks to `isna()`. Look at these functions over the web, you'll find some concrete examples, including in SO